# How to mock this simple method that creates kafka topic and waits for future object?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, powermockito

I am trying to mock this method that creates kafka topic and waits for future object to complete.
Not able to mock the below line:

createResult.values().get(topic).get();

Test case terminates with **NullPointerException** at the above line.

```
    @Test
    public void testCreateKafkaTopic(){

            MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

            PowerMockito.mockStatic(AdminClient.class);
            final KafkaAdminClient kafkaAdminClient = mock(KafkaAdminClient.class);
            NewTopic newTopicMock = mock(NewTopic.class);
            CreateTopicsResult createTopicsResultMock = mock(CreateTopicsResult.class);
            final KafkaFuture<Void> futureMock = mock(KafkaFuture.class);
            Map<String, KafkaFuture<Void>> map = mock(Map.class);



            PowerMockito.when(AdminClient.create(any(Properties.class))).thenReturn(kafkaAdminClient);
            PowerMockito.whenNew(NewTopic.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(newTopicMock);
            PowerMockito.when(createTopicsResultMock.values()).thenReturn(map);
            PowerMockito.when(map.get("fakeTopic").get()).thenReturn(futureMock);

            PowerMockito.when(futureMock.isDone()).thenReturn(true);
            myClass.createKafkaTopic("fakeTopic");

    }
}
```

Util class:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.CreateTopicsResult;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;

public class MyClass {

public void createKafkaTopic(String topic) { 
    AdminClient adminClient = null; 
    CreateTopicsResult createResult = null;
    NewTopic newTopic = null; 
    String bootStrapServers = "localhost:9092"; 
    try {
        adminClient = KafkaAdminClient.create(clientConfig(bootStrapServers)); 
        newTopic = new NewTopic(topic, 1, (short) 1); 
        createResult = adminClient.createTopics(Collections.singleton(newTopic)); 
        createResult.values().get(topic).get(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); } 
    }
}
```

Getting below error:

> Exception ocurred null java.lang.NullPointerException: at
>   createResult.values().get(topic).get();

Could you please help me to resolve the above error?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to break this line into 2

```
PowerMockito.when(map.get("fakeTopic").get()).thenReturn(futureMock);
```

Something like:

```
PowerMockito.when(map.get("fakeTopic")).thenReturn(entry);
PowerMockito.when(entry.get()).thenReturn(futureMock);
```

Basically, you hit a null pointer exception when your code tries to do get the topic `createResult.values().get(topic).get()` because `createResult.values().get(topic)` is null.

One extra thing: I would recommend using the dependency injection pattern rather than in method instantiation of Admin Client. Like that, you would be able to get rid of Powermockito and just use Mockito. Or at least move your admin client as a static class field and only instantiate once.

Comment: why don't you just wrap that `createResult.values().get(topic).get()` method into another, and mock the new one instead?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but, turns out to be code issue from my side.